# Jquery faster way to find a child of an element

Tags: jquery, arrays, dom

I have the following html and I wanted to get the inputs inside the divs

```
<div id="div1" >
    <input class="myinput" value="input inside div1"/>
 </div>

<div id="div2" >
   <input class="myinput" value="input inside div2"/>
</div>
```

To get the inputs I have two approaches the question is which one is preferred.So far I have tried the following two ways. Please suggest which one is better and why Or if there is other best ways of getting the child of an element by class name I am also open.

```
  var input1 = $("#div1 .myinput"); OR
  var input1 = $("#div1").find(".myinput");
```

Comment: The difference in performance is so minimal that it really doesn't matter. Use whatever feels more comfortable to you.

Comment: ... and do not use duplicate IDs.

Comment: I just edited my question to use class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gp3909a/1/) to compare the performance of both processes and consistently find that `$("#div1").find(".myinput");` is more efficient.

This makes sense to me. IIRC, the `#div1 .myinput` will first find all `.myinput` elements in the DOM then return only the one with an ancestor of `#div1`. Whereas, `#div1 .find(.myinput)` will only find the first `#div1` in the DOM then parse it's children, effectively reducing the amount of parsing needed, yielding a more efficient process.

**Previous answer prior to question edit:**

The fastest way would be to just use:

```
var input1 = $('#input');
```

Since ID attributes are supposed to be unique, adding anything else is pointless.

Comment: Please read the question carefully before rushing to asnwer I have two inputs with the same id and your approach would get me which ever is added at last.

Comment: @AmeteGirl Two inputs with the same ID is invalid HTML. I am proposing that you write code that complies with the standards.

Comment: ...or use a class instead of an id

Comment: Forget about storing as a variable which is is efficient?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.